# Triggers on Views in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, sql-view

I want to create a trigger for my view in PostgreSQL. The idea is that all new data must fulfill a condition to be inserted. But something is wrong here and I can't find the answer in manuals.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW My_View AS 
SELECT name, adress, count FROM club, band, country;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.count > 10) THEN
    INSERT INTO My_View VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.adress, NEW.count);
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON My_View
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert();
```

Comment: What is your postgresql version ? What is the error message you have ? Could you open a sandbox on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: My version is 9.1 And the error is strange, because it looks like almost never ending loop... the message is "stack overflow". And error is in that "INSERT"

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't call it insert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is a semicolon ( **;** )  missing at the end of the `INSERT` statement in the function.
- `insert` is a [**reserved word**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in the SQL standard and should not be used as trigger or function name. Even if it's allowed in PostgreSQL, it's a *very* bad idea.
- There are no join conditions for the three tables `club, band, country` in your view definition. This leads to a `CROSS JOIN`, which can be **extremely expensive**. If there are **1000** rows in each table, you get **1,000,000,000** combinations. You most definitely do not want that.
- Also, you should table-qualify the columns in your view definition to avoid ambiguities.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT ??.name, ??.address, ??.mycount
FROM club    cl
JOIN band    ba ON ?? = ??
JOIN country co ON ?? = ??;
```

You need to fill in where I left question marks.

- And always add a column definition list to your `INSERT` statements.
- And finally, you do **not** want to `INSERT` into the same view again, which would create an endless loop and may be the primary cause of your error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF NEW.mycount > 10 THEN
      INSERT INTO my_view ???? (col1?, col2?, col3?)
      VALUES (NEW.name, NEW.address, NEW.mycount);
   END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

BTW, you shouldn't use `count` as identifier either. I use `mycount`instead.

Comment: OK i get it, so how should i write that condition?

Comment: @Noran: If table `band` has a column `country_id` that refers to `country_id` of table `country`, you write: `JOIN country co ON co.country_id = ba.country_id` etc. You really need to understand these basics before you can even begin to mess with `INSTEAD` triggers on views.

Comment: Yes i know this and i understand this. I was thinking about that INSERT. Because the way: INSERT INTO col1, col2, col3 VALUES NEW.col1, NEW.col2, NEW.col3 doesnt work. I got syntax error there.

Comment: Huh... I am done, my brain is cooked. I will take a look on this tomorrow. THanks for your patience and help.

Comment: @Noran You're creating an infinite loop by having the trigger on the view try to insert into the view. Your `DO INSTEAD` trigger must insert into the underlying table(s) that the view `SELECT`s its data from. In this case you'd be inserting into `band`, `country` and/or `club`.

Comment: I get it now, there is nothing better then good help and a break ;) Thanks guys.